# sync execution in async c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

i want to run multiple transactions parallel using async call but in any transaction i want to process all the task in sequence because sequence matters.
i use async call but it doesn't help, it makes the whole transaction async which make conflict.

suppose i want to process data of multiple companies parallel, but data of company in sequence, i need productid of product to get detail of product so first i have to get all products and then get detail of product using productid against company.
i cant get product detail without productid.

```
Task WrappedInTask = Task.Run(() => CompanyAsync(companyId));
public static async Task CompanyAsync(int companyId)
    {
      string[] products=getAllProducts(compnyId);
       for(int i=0; i<products.length>i; i++)
          {
           //get product detail here using products[i]
          }
    }
```

i want to execute completely getAllProducts(compnyId) and then execute the for loop if for loop and getAllProducts(compnyId) method will exicute asynchronously then there will be conflict.
Any suggestion to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `getAllproducts(compnyId)` is an asynchronous method too, then you can simply wait for it to finish, before executing your for loop:

```
string[] products = await getAllProducts(compnyId);
for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
{
   // ...
}
```

Anyway, I don't know how your current code sample manages to compile. If `getallProducts` is in fact an `async` method, then `string[] products = getAllProducts(compnyId)` should throw an error, because it returns a `Task<string[]>` and not a `string[]`.

**EDIT**

You should not confuse parallelism with asynchronism.

It seems that you want to paralelly iterate over a list.

`async` methods are usually used if you are going to execute an inherently asynchronous operation (such as I/O), otherwise they are not needed.

You may use the [System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for your task.

```
//This will probably create new threads (or not) and will iterate your list concurrently
Parallel.ForEach(dt.Rows, dataRow =>
{
     int companyId = //Fetch companyId
     Company(companyId);
});

//Code here will execute after each element has been paralelly iterated.
```

Please note that your new `CompanyAsync` method signature should be changed to:

```
public static void Company(int companyId);
```

For further reference on how to use this approach, please read:

- [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: getAllProducts(compnyId) it is not async it is simple sync method

Comment: @MalikRizwan I'm sorry but if that's the case, then please try to reformulate your question because I'm not able to understand it correctly

Comment: only the outer method is async

Comment: simply i want sync execuion in async method. outer methods should be async and inner methods should be sync

Comment: @MalikRizwan Then why mark it as `async` in the first place if it is going to be synchronous?

Comment: outer method will be call multi times and will run async

Comment: foreach (int companyId in compnies)
                    {
                        Task WrappedInTask = Task.Run(() => ProductsAsync(companyId));
}

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function that returns a Task or a Task, than your code continuous performing the next statements while the Task is performing his own statements.

That is until you type the word "await". If you await a Task, you say: stop executing this code until the Task that I am awaiting for finished executing.

- Something that would normally return a void would as async function return a Task.
- Something that would normally return a TResult would as async function return a Task.

If you await a Task the return is the TResult that the task function would return if if wasn't async.

Now back to your question: if you want to start several Tasks, but need results from one or more from the started Tasks before you do the next statement (or start the next Task), you simply await for the Task before performing this next statement.

In its simplest form this would be:

```
private async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    int i = await DoXAsync();     // wait for X to finish before starting Y
    int j = await DoYAsync();     // wait for Y to finish before starting Z
    return await DoZAsync(i, j);  // wait until Z finished before returning
}
```

If you can run several tasks at the same time, start await when you need them.

```
private async Task<int> DoSomethingElseAsync()
{
    Task<int> taskX = DoXAsync();  // no await, continue with next statement
    Task<int> taskY = DoYAsync();  // no await, continue with next statement

    // now await until both tasks finished and use the result
    // for an await we need a Task or a Task<TResult>
    // Task.WaitAll is not suitable: it returns void
    // Task.WhenAll returns a Task. we can await for that
    await Task.WhenAll( new Task<int>[] {taskX, taskY});
    // the results of the task are in Task.Result.
    // note that only Task<TResult> has a Result.
    // Task is the async version of void return, so no result
    return await DoZAsync(taskX.Result, taskY.Result);
}
```